# How to namespace in a front controller situation using PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

Alright I have a tiny framework that I hope to open source soon and I'm trying to implement namespacing so that controllers and models don't need appended text. Here's the basic code logic:

- url request
- htaccess reroutes to index.php which initiates the framework
- framework parses route & determines which controller/action to instantiate & fire

  - the framework's front controller is 'Controller' & project controllers extend 'Controller'

So in order to allow for controllers to be named for example:

```
class Foo extends Controller {}
```

and later a model be:

```
class Foo extends Model {}
```

My directory structure is like so:

```
project/
    controllers/
        foo.php
    models/
        foo.php
```

So, I'm obviously needing to implement namespacing. (And yes, I'm running php 5.3). So my question is, how exactly would I implement namespacing where the front Controller and Model is extended by other controllers and models?

Comment: Interested in checking out the project as and when it is done.. !!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to manually prepend the namespace assuming your controllers are living in the same space.  Take the following example.

```
public function __construct( $controller, $model )
{
    $this->controller = 'Application\Controllers\\' . $controller;
    $this->model      = 'Application\Models\\'      . $model;
}
```

There may be a more autoload-ish way of doing it but I think this will suffice in most cases.  Don't quote me but perhaps you could use Reflection and get the namespace of the called object.  However, this may still require a more unique naming convention otherwise the autoloader still wouldn't know if you were calling `Controllers\Index.php` or `Views\Index.php`.

Answer (score -1):

Always check php.net... http://php.net/namespace

Comment: I've already perused php's namespace docs (isn't that usually a given?), however, the nature of my question is specific to namespacing with a front controller dynamically loading/firing project controllers. Meaning, I don't want people who use the framework having to Foo extends project\controllers\Controller. 'use project\controllers\Foo as Foo' is what I'm needing but this isn't dynamic and would still require being set in the project controller files. Make sense?

Comment: Ok, but I never saw (and see) the point of namespaces... Just name the classes properly...

Comment: Then you probably never developed app. with more than 10 classes.

Comment: actually, I did (and do)... Just name them properly! I never have to use double names, because none of my classes do the same thing (this would waste my time) so they have other names...

Comment: This isn't even a real answer. The question is very clear and concise and deserves more than a snarky RTFM notice. What he's looking for is not in the PHP manual and, if it was, this is not the appropriate way to point it out.

Comment: @dododedodonl The point of namespaces is not to delineate names amongst your own code.  Its for delineating names between different vendor code.  For example, if you used the database code from CodeIgniter and also needed some features from Laravel you could have both without name clashes by using namespaces.  Say both code bases have a `Connector` class; your autoloader would not know which one to load without namespaces.  **With** namepsaces, You could load `Database\CodeIgniter\Connector` and `Database\Laravel\Connector` without conflict.